# Centering image does not work

Tags: css, image

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="tex/css">
 body{
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  color: #665544;
 }
 img.align-center {
  display:block;
  margin:0px auto;
 }
 img.medium{
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
 }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
 <p><img src="../../Images/magnolia-medium.jpg" alt="Magnolia" class="align-
    center medium" /><b><i>Magnolia</i></b> is a large genus that contains over 
    200 flowering plant species. It is named after French botanist Pierre Magnol 
     and, having evolved before bees appeared, the flowers were developed to 
     encourage pollination by beetle.</p>
    </body>
   </html>
```

image should be centered but I see the image on the left side of the window. What's the problem????

Comment: `<style type="tex/css">` I guess there is a typo. Should be `<style type="text/css">`

Comment: @MuthuKumaran what the....... oh THAT SOLVED  ...thanks

Comment: @MuthuKumaran Using Notepad++.. almost impossible to find typos shiiiiit

Comment: that issued the fixed?

Comment: @MuthuKumaran .... yes. As you mentioned it was just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** `<style type="tex/css">`

```
                 ^----------------text no tex
```

**2)** Change Like :

```
p {
  margin:0px auto;
  width: 250px;
}

img.medium {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
 body {
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
   color: #665544;
 }

 p {
   margin:0px auto;
   width: 250px;
 }

 img.medium {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="http://justcuteanimals.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/baby-bear-pictures-cute-animal-pics.jpg
" alt="Magnolia" class="align-
    center medium" />
  <b>
    <i>Magnolia</i>
  </b>
    is a large genus that contains over 
    200 flowering plant species. It is named after French botanist Pierre Magnol 
    and, having evolved before bees appeared, the flowers were developed to 
    encourage pollination by beetle.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

There were spaces between `align-` and `center` in your code. Removing the spaces results into the below.

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  color: #665544;
}

.align-center {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.medium {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<p><img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="Magnolia" class="align-center medium" />
<b><i>Magnolia</i></b> is a large genus that contains over 200 flowering plant species. It is named after French botanist Pierre Magnol and, having evolved before bees appeared, the flowers were developed to encourage pollination by beetle.</p>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this, Hope it will work for you;
`.align-center img {
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
}`

Comment: Can you please explain why you believe this selector `.align-center img` is an improvement over this one `img.align-center`? What changes to make the image align in the middle?

Comment: i tried your suggestion. Changed img.align-center to .align-center image does not work.

Comment: Keep class name only "align- center".

Comment: `.align-center img` would select img with .align-center parent, like `<div class="align-center"><img/></div>`. That's not the case here.